# WebUtility.HtmlDecode and HttpUtility.HtmlDecode not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code which is not working..

```
var sampleText = "Mahindra &amp;amp; Mahindra announced that it is banking on its tractor business in the US and it expects to double its revenues to $1 billion in the ...";
var webDecoded = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(sampleText);
var httpDecoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sampleText);
```

Here are the output:

[image: WebDecoded]

[image: HttpDecoded]

Correct output should be: Mahindra & Mahindra announced...

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get `Mahindra & Mahindra announced`, then the correct input should be `Mahindra &amp; Mahindra announced`.

You have an extra `amp;`: `Mahindra &amp;amp; Mahindra announced`

Comment: I parse this string from [rss](http://www.investmentguruindia.com/RSS/Stock-News). It seems source is not encoded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The code is working correctly.  This input string:

```
"&amp;amp;"
```

When HTML-decoded, results in this output string:

```
"&amp;"
```

Because `&amp;` decodes to `&`.

The string has an extra `amp;` in it, which doesn't decode to anything because it's not an HTML code.  So the decoder is treating it like any other text.

That output string can be decoded *again*, which would turn the resulting `&amp;` into `&`.